# Why am I getting the error '' when trying to build FFmpeg under Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ffmpeg

I am trying to build FFmpeg to run under Ubuntu Server 16.04. I am running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg

git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git

cd FFmpeg

./configure   --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openal --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-libssh --enable-libsoxr --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-libx265

make -j8
sudo make install
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: frei0r.h header not found
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That seems like an excessive amount of less than useful external libraries that you are enabling support for. Do you really need a fixed-point MP3 encoder, non-native RTMP support, WebPee support, a text-to-speech encoder, etc, etc, etc?

Comment: Follow the [Compilation Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) at `ffmpeg` to avoid any errors. P.S.:- Since you are enabling all the codecs, make sure you have installed all of them prior to the final compilation command of `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`frei0r.h` is in the [frei0r-plugins-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/frei0r-plugins-dev) packcage.
Try install that package(e.g. `sudo aptitude install frei0r-plugins-dev`).

Answer (score 0):

you could also remove `--enable-frei0r` from the arguments given to configure.

assuming it's not necessary to you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1343218)